# Google charts using database result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I have one code page (see below) written in Ruby on Rails.
I want to display some monthly distances.
I have a local variable @result storing the data set I need, 22 records, 3 columns (got it in the controller from the database). Here is a sample of the data:

```
year_month | tbm_1_distance | tbm_2_distance 
------------+----------------+----------------
2013-06    |         13.250 |               
...              
2013-09    |         45.000 |         51.780
2013-10    |        131.970 |         51.160
...
2015-01    |        315.050 |        315.050
2015-02    |        287.150 |        287.150
2015-03    |        241.800 |        241.800
```

I am hardcoding these values in var aa = ..
But I want to build var aa using a loop through the result set.
aa is going to be used in data.addRows(aa);
Don't know how to do it in Java script section of the code.
All examples I found in the doc are with hard coded values or locally generated with "new", nothing coming from a database result set.

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <% provide(:title, "TBM Monthly Progress") %>
  <h1>
    TBM Monthly Progress
  </h1>

  <h4>
    Number of months: <%=@result.count%>
  </h4>
  <%= render 'main/tbms_main_subnav' %>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>

  <br><br>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'main/unsigned' %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var aa = [
      ['2013-06', 13.250,               0],
      ['2013-07', 45.650,               0],
      ['2013-08', 60.000,               0],
      ['2013-09', 45.000,         51.780],
      ['2013-10', 131.970,         51.160],
      ['2013-11', 166.310,         77.900],
      ['2013-12', 233.790,          0.000],
      ['2014-01', 214.060,        169.630],
      ['2014-02', 151.400,        150.090],
      ['2014-03', 13.880,        329.440],
      ['2014-04', 343.280,        268.280],
      ['2014-05', 338.750,        310.410],
      ['2014-06', 370.470,        342.870],
      ['2014-07', 421.500,        357.340],
      ['2014-08', 323.940,        359.040],
      ['2014-09', 294.890,        294.370],
      ['2014-10', 309.750,        310.050],
      ['2014-11', 284.850,        284.850],
      ['2014-12', 284.950,        284.950],
      ['2015-01', 315.050,        315.050],
      ['2015-02', 287.150,        287.150],
      ['2015-03', 241.800,        241.800]
    ];
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year-Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'TBM 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'TBM 2');
    data.addRows(aa);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title:    'TBM Excavated Distances per month',
        subtitle: 'TBM 1 in blue, TBM 2 in red'
      },
      bars: 'horizontal'
    };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is in `@result`?

Comment: 22 records like the few I put at the beginning of my question, 3 columns.

Comment: Is it an array of arrays then?

Comment: The content of @result is hardcoded in var aa. I want to eliminate the hardcode and replace it with a loop.

Comment: I want to eliminate the assignment var aa = [ [],[], ..] and to build it using a loop through @result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "pass" `@result` in a `div` with `data-distances`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="dual_x_div" ... data-distances="<%= @result %>"></div>
</div>
```

and then say `var aa = $("#dual_x_div").data("distances")`

For more about how to pass data to javascript check [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) and for more about the custom data-* attributes, check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Comment: Does not work, chart is not shown which means the array is not build.

Comment: @L.D Can you inspect the `dual_x_div` with developer tools and tell me what is in `data-distances`?

Comment: <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" data-distances="#&lt;PG::Result:0x007f9937dfd220&gt;"><svg width="916" height="500"><defs><filter x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%" id="rablshadow4"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="0" dy="0"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><filter x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%" id="rablshadow3"> ... </svg></div>

Comment: This `data-distances="#&lt;PG::Result:0x007f9937dfd220&gt;"` makes me think that `@result` is not an array of arrays.

Comment: I am working to change that. I will transform in the controller the PG:Result in an array of arrays.

Comment: Chart is still missing, but now I am sure I am using an array of arrays: 
  <div class="row">
    <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" data-distances="[[&quot;2013-06&quot;, &quot;13.250&quot;, &quot;0&quot;], [&quot;2013-07&quot;, &quot;45.650&quot;, &quot;0&quot;], [&quot;2013-08&quot;, &quot;60.000&quot;, &quot;0&quot;], [&quot;2013-09&quot;, &quot;315.050&quot;, &quot;315.050&quot;], [&quot;2015-02&quot;, &quot;287.150&quot;, &quot;287.150&quot;], [&quot;2015-03&quot;, &quot;241.800&quot;, &quot;241.800&quot;]]"></div>
  </div>

Comment: The error is: [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: distances
 drawChart (tbms_monthly_progress, line 259)

Comment: @L.D Update your question with your progress and we can take it from there :)

Comment: I found the error, I deleted by mistake the line: var aa = $("#dual_x_div").data("distances"); Now everything works. Thanks!

Comment: There was also another reason why the chart was not rendered. When converting the PG Result distances has to be changed from string to numbers using to_f.

Comment: @L.D That's why it's very important to be precise regarding what is what. Glad it worked!